# H2O python merge fails on big table >400 Mio rows with error Temp ID py_XX already exists

Tags: python, merge, h2o

Im trying to do a merge with two h2o.frames (frame1.shape: (470 Mio, 90), frame2.shape: (1Mio, 10)) but it raises my the same error all the time, it says Temp ID already exists.

frame1.merge(frame2, all_x=False, all_y=False, by_x=[3], by_y=[0])

H2O 3.8.2.3 python merge fails on big table >400 Mio rows with error

ERROR MESSAGE:

Temp ID py_3 already exists

- I restarted the Cluster already
- It works just fine with smaller row size of frame1

Is this a bug? Or is there a limit to the size of the dataframes for merges?

Comment: There is no limit on the size of frames that can merged.  Your only limitation is the memory of your cluster.  Is this still not working on the latest stable version of H2O?